# Blender 2.8 not allowing me to change the 3d cursor

Tags: modeling, 3d-cursor

I been trying to change the 3D cursor and when i change the world origin and press shift + S and select any of the options that would move the cursor, it just doesn't move it. Do you guys know of any reason why this would happen and a way to resolve that?

Comment: What do you mean by 'change the world origin'? Do you mean you moved the 3D cursor there? Did you have something else selected?

Comment: Yeah. Whenever i try to do that, it just doesn't work.